# Render Rails 3.1 view quicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, optimization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app that has the following view:

```html
<style>
    table.diary tbody tr td {
    background :transparent;
    }

    td {
    padding: 4px;
    <% if current_user.is_transport_user? %>
    cursor: pointer;
    <% end %>
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    td.dashed-cell {
    border: 3px solid #CCCCCC;
    min-width: 150px;
    }
    td.provisional {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    min-width: 150px;
    }
    td.unexpected {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #FF0000;
    min-width: 150px;
    }
    td.moved {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #FFCC00;
    min-width: 150px;
    }
    td.confirmed {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid #006600;
    min-width: 150px;
    }

    #toolbar {
    padding: 10px 4px;
    }
</style>

<span id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" size=30>
    <button id="today">
        today
    </button> </span>
<p>
    <table class="diary">
        <thead>
            <th> Time </th>
            <% if current_user.is_booking_manager? %> <th> Pallets </th>
            <th> Slots </th>
            <% end %>
        </thead>
        <% @slot_times.each do |slot_time| %>
        <tr class="slot_time" id="slot_time<%= slot_time.id %>">
            <td class="time-cell"> <%= slot_time.datetime.strftime('%H:%M') %> </td>
            <% if current_user.is_booking_manager? %> <td class="pallets"> <%= slot_time.number_of_pallets %> </td>
            <td class="button_bar"> <%= form_for slot_time, :url => diary_slot_time_set_capacity_path(@site, slot_time) do |f| %>
            <%= f.number_field :capacity, :id=>"capacity#{slot_time.id}", :size=>2, :min=>0, :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' %>
            <% end %>
            <%= button_to "Add", diary_slot_time_add_slot_path(@site, slot_time), :remote => true, :id => "add_slot" %>
            <%= button_to "Remove", diary_slot_time_remove_slot_path(@site, slot_time), :remote => true, :id => "remove_slot#{slot_time.id}", :disabled => disable_remove?(slot_time) %> </td>
            <% end %>

            <% slot_time.bookings_visible_to(current_user).each do |booking| %>
            <% unless booking.id.nil? %>
            <%= render :partial => "booking", :locals => { :booking => booking } %>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>

            <% for i in 1..slot_time.number_of_free_slots %>
            <%= render :partial => "free_slot", :locals => { :slot_time => slot_time } %>
            <% end %>

            <% slot_time.bookings.each do |booking| %>
            <% if booking.id.nil? %>
            <div style="display:none;">
                <div id="create_booking<%= slot_time.id %>" title="Create Booking">
                    <%= render :partial => "booking_dialog", :locals => { :booking => booking } %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
    <script>

        $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat : "DD, d MM, yy",
            onSelect : function(dateText, inst) {
                var newdate = new Date(dateText);
                var yyyy = newdate.getFullYear().toString();
                var mm = (newdate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                var dd = newdate.getDate().toString();
                if(mm.length == 1) {
                    mm = '0' + mm;
                }
                if(dd.length == 1) {
                    dd = '0' + dd;
                }
                document.location.href = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            }
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date("<%= @slot_day.day %>"));
    });

    $("#today").button().click(function() {
        document.location.href = "<%= diary_url(@site) %>";
    });

    </script>
```

What I wish to do is speed up the rendering of this view which is currently at:

```
Rendered slot_days/_booking_dialog.html.erb (3.7ms)
Rendered slot_days/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1488.0ms)  
AdminLevel Load (0.2ms)
  SELECT "admin_levels".* FROM "admin_levels" WHERE "admin_levels"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Site Load (0.2ms)
  SELECT "sites".* FROM "sites"
Completed 200 OK in 1818ms (Views: 1493.5ms | ActiveRecord: 39.9ms)
```

What is the best way to speed this view up?

I understand some may well comment on this post stating that I should have my and javascript in the asset pipeline. However you will notice that on my CSS under the td I have erb stanzas as so in my javascript. If I were to put this into the asset pipeline surely this will conflict and cause my css and javascript to stop working.

Comment: As for the JavaScript and CSS, there's no reason to have ERb in your CSS when instead you could e.g. toggle a class attribute (with ERb) on the relevant HTML tag. The JavaScript should be moved into a `.erb.js` at the very least. These issues aren't causing your performance issue, but definitely deserve your attention.

Comment: How many items are in `@slot_times` and how many `bookings` does each one have? You're performing several loops within another loop which is probably the source of your performance issues. Can you eliminate any of these or consolidate them into a single loop (perhaps in your controller, if only for readability)? Consider doing some [deeper profiling](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#view) to figure out where the most time is going.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first decouple your file into several ones.
One for each type of data: css, javascript, html.

That way you can take advantage of the asset pipeline provided by Rails.

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

You can try caching.

Either action caching in your controller:

`caches_page :action_name`

or on the view itself, fragment caching. Something like

```
<% cache do %>
 All available products:
 <% Product.all.each do |p| %>
  <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Helpful Link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html